# Terminal input doesn't match expected result

Tags: go, gofmt

I am new to Go.

I wrote the program below to allow a user to enter the name.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    fmt.Print("Enter name:")
    name, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(name == "nixon")
}
```

I ran the program and entered my name **nixon**

Why is it that the output of `fmt.Println(name == "nixon")` is always `false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [func (*Reader) ReadString](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString)
>
> ```
> func (b *Reader) ReadString(delim byte) (string, error)
> ```
>
> ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input,
>   returning a string containing the data up to and including the
>   delimiter.

---

`name` terminal input includes trailing newlines. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    fmt.Print("Enter name:")
    name, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", name)

    fmt.Println(name == "nixon")
}
```

Output (Linux):

```
Enter name:nixon
"nixon\n"
false
```

Output (Windows):

```
Enter name:nixon
"nixon\r\n"
false
```

---

Trim trailing newlines. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    fmt.Print("Enter name:")
    name, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", name)
    name = strings.TrimRight(name, "\r\n")
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", name)

    fmt.Println(name == "nixon")
```

}

Output (Linux):

```
Enter name:nixon
"nixon\n"
"nixon"
true
```

Output (Windows):

```
Enter name:nixon
"nixon\r\n"
"nixon"
true
```

Comment: Just added this and it worked!

`name = strings.TrimRight(name, "\r\n")`
\o

Answer (score 1):

modify your main function as following:

```
func main() {
  reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

  fmt.Print("Enter name:")
  name, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  name = strings.TrimSuffix(name, "\n")
  fmt.Println(name == "nixon")
}
```

The line I added to your code trims new line char from your input.